# watchOS simple wakeup

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

Here is some watchOS code I have working on the Similator(Watch):

```
.....
let interval = 60.0
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval,
                                       target: self,
                                       selector: #selector(InterfaceController.timerDidEnd(_:)),
                                       userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
.....

func timerDidEnd(timer:NSTimer) {
    print("Time is over! Please wake up!")
}
```

From Xcode I run the app, the first part of the code above gets executed. Then I hit Command-Shift-H and the app goes in the background.

After one minute I see in the debugging console the message: *Time is over! Please wake up!*

All works as I expect. My question is:

What should I write inside the function timerDidEnd(), in order to have the app wake up from the background on the simulator, rather than just printing the current message in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can write inside a timer action that will bring an app to the foreground.  Only the user can resume an app.

If you think about it, it would confusing and disruptive for the user if an app could programmatically bring itself to the foreground whenever it wanted.

The only way to resume an app is by the user reacting to a notification.  This is similar to what happens on the phone when the user taps notification actions from the home screen.

Comment: I see, you have a point. Now, how about this situation: you and your app are both sleeping. But you count on your app to wake you up in the morning. How do we handle such a case?

Comment: You schedule a local notification on the watch, using the new UserNotifications framework.  Notification appears in the morning, with sound/haptic feedback.  Apple could do this in watchOS 2.  Now we can do something similar in watchOS 3.  Again, notifications are the key to what you want to do.